# Select first object of group by in postgresql/sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a request in sqlachemy with SQLite which return an object of the group by and a value (avg) :

```
result = session.query(
        obj, func.avg(obj.value).label("value_avg")
    ).group_by(
        func.strftime('%s', obj.date)
    ).all()
```

But now i need to use postgresql which is more restrictive (strict SQL) and i need to do the same thing but it need to replace query(obj) by something in the group by like func.avg() or something else. So i would like to know if exist any func which can be able to return the first obj of each group. If not possible maybe i can implement comparator for my obj and for instance call func.min(obj) like this :

```
result = session.query(
        func.min(obj), func.avg(obj.value).label("value_avg")
    ).group_by(
        func.date_part('second', obj.date)
    ).all()
```

And maybe implement **cmp** and **eq** in my obj model ? (What is the best practice)

EDIT :

I got a workaround but i'm not sure it's a good practice. First group by and next join :

```
sq = session.query(
        func.min(obj.date).label("date"), func.avg(obj.value).label("value_avg")
    ).group_by(
        func.cast(func.extract('second', obj.date) / 600, Integer)
    ).order_by(obj.date).subquery()
result = session.query(obj, sq.c.value_avg).join(sq,sq.c.date == obj.date).all()
```

What i want is the first obj of each group and value_avg of the group

Comment: Your solution (generally) could return multiple results. Unless the value in `min()` is unique (which I guess it is, because `id` sound like a primary key; but if it's only a foreign key, that might not be the case). -- This is a specialized case of [tag:greatest-n-per-group] (where N=1). There are a plenty of SQL solutions already here on SO, but I don't know which is the most suitable for [SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy+greatest-n-per-group).

Comment: Sorry I edit Id to date and date is the index so unique.

Comment: but that doesn't make much sense, because `SELECT min(date) ... GROUP BY date` and `SELECT date ... GROUP BY date` is the same (there is only one `date` in the `date` group anyway). -- Also, a single index doesn't guarantee its uniqueness.

Comment: Yes i agree but in my result i have access to other attribut which i need. With SQlite i didn't have this problem as you can this in the first case because of `query(obj, func.avg(obj.value).label("value_avg"))` which give me access to obj attributs

Comment: Why not use [over()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over) if you need to select both aggregated and non-aggregated value?

Comment: How would you do that ?

Comment: I have given example as answer, but I never used SQL Alchemy so I'm not sure if it is correct syntax. But to put it simply, you move `GROUP BY your_column_list` into `SELECT [..] avg(value) over(PARTITION BY your_column_list)`

Comment: Do you need to get non-aggregated (not avg()) column "value" in your query? Are you doing anything with that data or was this just convenience and you didn't want to list columns that you actually want to retrieve from db?

Comment: Yes foreign key for instance and other value which it will be difficult to aggregate

Comment: I have replaced my answer with what I think will be correct one this time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to list all columns that you want to select and put them in group_by. Then you can select aggregated columns that are not part of the group by.

```
result = session.query(
    obj.column1,
    obj.column2,
    obj.column3,
    func.strftime('%s', obj.date),
    func.avg(obj.value).label("value_avg")
).group_by(
    obj.column1,
    obj.column2,
    obj.column3,
    obj.date
).all()
```

Comment: Yes but it's not easy when you have to deal with foreign object like obj.obj2.obj3 with lazy query